# Smooth Expanding and Collapsing Animation for WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to get a smooth expanding and collapsing animation for my form. My current animation is really jittery and non consistent. Heres a Gif of the [Animation](https://i.gyazo.com/e18bda26e5b4679b756423cb71a1b8cd.gif). Is there another way to do this that doesnt freeze the form?

```
private void ShowHideToggle_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ShowHideToggle.Checked) //checked = expand form
        {
            ShowHideToggle.Text = "<";
            while (Width < originalWidth)
            {
                Width++;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ShowHideToggle.Text = ">";
            while(Width > 24)
            {
                Width--;
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As an added note, you should avoid `DoEvents`...[it's really bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181777/use-of-application-doevents).

Comment: _Smooth .. Animation_ and _WinForms_ do not go together well, I'm sorry to say..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Timer`:

```
Timer t = new Timer();
t.Interval = 14;
t.Tick += delegate
{
    if (ShowHideToggle.Checked)
    {
        if (this.Width > 30) // Set Form.MinimumSize to this otherwise the Timer will keep going, so it will permanently try to decrease the size.
            this.Width -= 10;
        else
            t.Stop();
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.Width < 300)
            this.Width += 10;
        else
            t.Stop();
    }
};
```

And change your code to:

```
private void ShowHideToggle_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: its a bit slow. any other ideas?

Comment: `t.Interval = 2;` this is an illusion; 15-25 are more realistic values..

Comment: Increase `this.Width`. I changed the code in the answer.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something...it looks like this will tack on an additional event handler every time the thing is clicked?

Comment: Yeah, tested it and after it activates a few times... So I changed it.